# EPPlus - Write Excel File with more than 26 columns, C#/MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I am using EPPlus to create an Excel file to in my MVC Project. I want to create a spreadsheet that will contain 30 columns.

With my current code, the spreadsheet maxes out at 26 columns (named A - Z). I know I need to change the range to include AA - ZZ columns, but I am not sure how to do that.  Should I be referring to the columns by a int instead?  I don't see any sample of this on the GitHub site.

Here is my code (Excel data coming from a data table (dt)):

```
 //return dt;  
 using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
  {
      //Create the worksheet
      ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Claims");
      //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);

                //prepare the range for the column headers
                string cellRange = "A1:" + Convert.ToChar('A' + dt.Columns.Count - 1) + 1;

                //Format the header for columns
                using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[cellRange])
                {
                    rng.Style.WrapText = false;
                    rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; 
                    //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                    rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
                    rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
                }

                //prepare the range for the rows
                string rowsCellRange = "A2:" + Convert.ToChar('A' + dt.Columns.Count - 1) + dt.Rows.Count * dt.Columns.Count;

                //Format the rows
                using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[rowsCellRange])
                {
                    rng.Style.WrapText = true;
                    rng.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
                }

               //Read the Excel file in a byte array
                Byte[] fileBytes = pck.GetAsByteArray();
                //Clear the response
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.Cookies.Clear();
                //Add the header & other information 
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
                Response.CacheControl = "private";
                Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Claims.xlsx");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                //Write it back to the client
                Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
                Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Use ints. Format: "ws.Cells[row, column]"

Comment: I was able to simply convert to ws.Cells[1,1] to get this to work, but how do I format the header row then?  I had the first row / header row in bold text with background yellow.  How do I address this now (see the code above under the //Format the header for columns comment).  I am receiving this error -{"Invalid Address format ]1"} on line: using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[cellRange]

Comment: using (var range = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, 11])  //format: ws.Cells[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol]
                {
                    range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    range.Style.ShrinkToFit = false;
                    range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    range.AutoFilter = true;
                }

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  If you'd like to post this, I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ints to allow for ease of use.
Format: "ws.Cells[row, column]"

Use this code for setting the headers:

```
                using (var range = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, 11])  //format: ws.Cells[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol]
            {
                range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                range.Style.ShrinkToFit = false;
                range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                range.AutoFilter = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all as I can see in your comments as workSmarter said you can use `ws.Cells[row,col]` format for addressing a cell.
But you can also load a generic IEnumerable (IEnumerable) in your Excel with EPPlus. Here is a method that write a generic IEnumerable in Excel using `LoadFromCollection` Method. In this example I used reflection to create the header row based on T properties:

```
public FileContentResult WriteToExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, string fileName, bool shouldGenerateSumRow = true)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
        {

            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("گزارش");
            ws.View.RightToLeft = true;
            var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            var RowCount = data.Count();

            ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(data, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium27);
            ws.InsertRow(1, 1);
            var excelRange = ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, props.Count];
            ws.Row(1).Height = 80;

            excelRange.Merge = true;
            excelRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.CenterContinuous;
            excelRange.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
            excelRange.Style.WrapText = true;
            excelRange.Value = fileName;

            for (var i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[2, i + 1].Value = props[i].DisplayName;
            }


            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

            var fcr = new FileContentResult(package.GetAsByteArray(),
                "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                FileDownloadName = $"{fileName}.xlsx"
            };
            return fcr;
        }
    }
```